# Can I refork the deleted repository in the github?

Tags: git, github

Consider this scenario -
I have two repositories in the github
**1) Repository A with project as ProjectA
2) Repository B**

I forked projectA from repository A into repository B

Now I have the repositories status as -
**1) Repository A with project as ProjectA
2) Repository B with forked project from Repository A as ProjectA**

Now I made number of changes in forked project ProjectA in repository B.

Now I want to delete the forked project ProjectA in repositoy B.

I could easily do that by going to **settings -> Delete this repository** of repository B.

My question is '**After deleting the projectA in repository B, Can I refork the projectA from repository A to repository B?**'.

The question could be silly but deleting the project in github is a risky affair so just wanted to confirm before doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> After deleting the projectA in repository B, Can I refork the projectA from repository A to repository B?

Yes, considering the name "`repoB`" is not taken (since you just deleted it, which [deletes the fork](https://help.github.com/articles/deleting-a-repository/))
It won't do anything to `repoA`.

Even if somehow `repoB` wasn't allowed, you would still be able to fork `repoA` under a different name.

Comment: So I will go to 1) repo A  2) click on ProjectA 3)Click on fork 4) It will give me options which repo A or B  5) I will choose A 6) If the same name wont allow then change the name is that what you meant to say?

Comment: @GauravP you can delete your repoB, go back to repoA and click fork again.

Comment: @GauravP It won't give you the option for repoB, since you just deleted repoB.

Comment: I deleted repository and reforked from other  user repository it worked, I did not need name change. Thanks for suggestion.